# How can I restart a double linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm coding a program to multiply two polynomials. I need some advice as to how I can restart the double linked list in the nested while loop in the polyProduct function. I mean, at this point I need to go back to the first position of the list. This is the code I have so far:

```
#include "DLListInterface.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int numRead(DLnode*,int);
void printList(DLnode*);
DLnode *polyProduct(DLnode*,DLnode*);

int main()
{
    DLnode *number1;
    DLnode *number2;
    DLnode *result;
    int readval;
    int numbterms;
    int i;

    scanf("%d",&numbterms);
    scanf("%d",&readval);

    /* initial DLnode of number1*/
    number1=(DLnode*)malloc(sizeof(DLnode));
    number1->value=readval;
    number1->next=NULL;
    number1->prev=NULL;

    readval=numRead(number1,numbterms);

    scanf("%d",&numbterms);
    scanf("%d",&readval);

    number2=(DLnode*)malloc(sizeof(DLnode));
    number2->value=readval;
    number2->next=NULL;
    number2->prev=NULL;

    readval=numRead(number2,numbterms);

    printf("\n");
    printList(number1);
    printList(number2);
    result=polyProduct(number1,number2);
    printList(result);

    getch();
    return 0;
}

int numRead(DLnode*number,int numbterms)
{
    int readval,i;
    DLnode *anothernode;
    for(i=0;i<(numbterms*2)-1;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&readval);
        anothernode=(DLnode*)malloc(sizeof(DLnode));
        anothernode->value=readval;
        anothernode->next=NULL;
        anothernode->prev=Dlast(number);
        Dlast(number)->next=anothernode;
    }
    return readval;
}


DLnode *polyProduct(DLnode*poly1,DLnode*poly2)
{
    DLnode *result;
    DLnode *newnode;
    DLnode *first;
    first=poly2;

    newnode=(DLnode*)malloc(sizeof(DLnode));
    newnode->value=(poly1->value)*(poly2->value);
    newnode->next=NULL;
    newnode->prev=NULL;
    result=newnode;

    poly1=poly1->next;
    poly2=poly2->next;

    newnode=(DLnode*)malloc(sizeof(DLnode));
    newnode->value=poly1->value+poly2->value;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    newnode->prev=Dlast(result);
    Dlast(result)->next=newnode;

    poly1=poly1->prev;
    poly2=poly2->next;


    while(poly1!=NULL)
    {
        while(poly2!=NULL)
        {
            newnode=(DLnode*)malloc(sizeof(DLnode));
            newnode->value=(poly1->value)*(poly2->value);
            newnode->next=NULL;
            newnode->prev=Dlast(result);
            Dlast(result)->next=newnode;

            poly1=poly1->next;
            poly2=poly2->next;

            newnode=(DLnode*)malloc(sizeof(DLnode));
            newnode->value=poly1->value+poly2->value;
            newnode->next=NULL;
            newnode->prev=Dlast(result);
            Dlast(result)->next=newnode;

            poly1=poly1->prev;
            poly2=poly2->next;

        }
        poly1=poly1->next;
        poly2=first; //restart poly 2

    }
    return result;

}


void printList(DLnode*number)
{
    while (number!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",number->value);
        number=number->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

//Declaration of DLnode in DLList.h file
typedef struct Dcontainer
{
    int value;
    struct Dcontainer *next;
    struct Dcontainer *prev;

} DLnode;
```

Comment: If there is a `Dlast` function, is it possible there's a `Dfirst` function?

Comment: You don't seem to be storing exponents along with the coefficients, so I'm not sure quite how you're representing polynomials.  Which polynomial (linked list) are you seeking to 'restart'?  You seem to have `first` so you can go back to the beginning of the second polynomial on each iteration.  Do you need to edit the output list as you're going?  You need to keep tabs on the start of the output polynomial simply so you can return it, and you can restart it.  But you need to think about how to get the result manually. (ax2 + bx + c).(dx2+ex+f) = adx4+(ae+bd)x3+(fa+be+cd)x2+(ce+bf)x+cf?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The number1 and number2 lists contains the coefficient and the exponent one after the other. My idea is to multiply the coefficient and add the exponent of every term in the number2 list with the first term of the number1 list and after that continue with the next term of number1 list. But I have a problem when the number2 list reach his end. I think I better try to separate the product and the add operations.

Comment: @dreamlax Yes, the methods of the list are there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of going to the start of the list is to manipulate the pointer to move to the start of the list

```
void seekstart(DLNode* number)
{
     while(number->prev != null)
     {
        number = number->prev;
     }
}
```

The other option is use temporary nodes to store the Starting node of the list before processing.

```
DLnode *temp_num1 = number1;
DLnode *temp_num2 = number2;
result=polyProduct(number1,number2);
```

Or You keep a pointer to the root in the structure of the node itself. Although this might not be an efficient solution. It is quite helpful if you need to access the starting of the list quite frequently

//Declaration of DLnode in DLList.h file

```
typedef struct Dcontainer
{
int value;
struct Dcontainer *next;
struct Dcontainer *prev;
struct Dcontainer *root;    //root is the starting of the list
} DLnode;
```